# Jenkins pipeline and Microsoft Teams - custom message has no newlines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, microsoft-teams, jenkins-groovy

I integrated Jenkins with Office 365 Connector plugin in order to send messages to a Teams channel.

Although, in the pipeline script I am using the multi-line string for `message` parameter, the whole information in Teams is displayed in one row.

Here is my code in the pipeline:

```
office365ConnectorSend (
                webhookUrl: 'webhookUrl',
                color: "${currentBuild.currentResult}" == 'SUCCESS' ? '#00ff00' : '#ff0000',
                message: """
                Here is the [Regression Report](${env.BUILD_URL}/Extent_20Report/) from $date:
                *Total*: $tc_total
                *Passed*: $tc_passed
                *Skipped*: $tc_skipped
                *Failed*: $tc_failed
                """,
                status: "${currentBuild.currentResult.toLowerCase()}",
            )
```

This is what I see in Teams:
[image: Message displayed in Teams]

(As you can see, the whole string is squeezed into one line.)

This is what I want my message to look like:

[image]

I tried to add newline `\n` character at the end of each line:

```
office365ConnectorSend (
                webhookUrl: 'webhookUrl',
                color: "${currentBuild.currentResult}" == 'SUCCESS' ? '#00ff00' : '#ff0000',
                message: """
                Here is the [Regression Report](${env.BUILD_URL}/Extent_20Report/) from $date: \n
                *Total*: $tc_total \n
                *Passed*: $tc_passed \n
                *Skipped*: $tc_skipped \n
                *Failed*: $tc_failed
                """,
                status: "${currentBuild.currentResult.toLowerCase()}",
            )
```

And even though it helped, but not in an expected way:

[image: Message in Teams after adding newlines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newlines turn the indented lines in the markdown into ```` ```code``` ```` formatting. Try using e.g. bulleted lists, or insert `<br/>` where you want a break (assuming Teams supports this; given its provenance, I would not put my hopes very high).

```
office365ConnectorSend (
                webhookUrl: 'webhookUrl',
                color: "${currentBuild.currentResult}" == 'SUCCESS' ? '#00ff00' : '#ff0000',
                message: """
Here is the [Regression Report](${env.BUILD_URL}/Extent_20Report/) from $date:
* *Total*: $tc_total
* *Passed*: $tc_passed
* *Skipped*: $tc_skipped 
* *Failed*: $tc_failed
                """,
                status: "${currentBuild.currentResult.toLowerCase()}",
            )
```

The asterisks create a bulleted list, which renders here on Stack Overflow in the local Markdown dialect as

> Here is the [Regression Report](//) from $date:
>
> - *Total*: $tc_total
> - *Passed*: $tc_passed
> - *Skipped*: $tc_skipped
> - *Failed*: $tc_failed

Here is the same with `<br/>`s:

```
office365ConnectorSend (
                webhookUrl: 'webhookUrl',
                color: "${currentBuild.currentResult}" == 'SUCCESS' ? '#00ff00' : '#ff0000',
                message: """
Here is the [Regression Report](${env.BUILD_URL}/Extent_20Report/) from $date: <br/>
*Total*: $tc_total<br/>
*Passed*: $tc_passed<br/>
*Skipped*: $tc_skipped <br/>
*Failed*: $tc_failed
                """,
                status: "${currentBuild.currentResult.toLowerCase()}",
            )
```

which renders as

> Here is the [Regression Report](//) from $date: 
> *Total*: $tc_total 
> *Passed*: $tc_passed 
> *Skipped*: $tc_skipped 
> *Failed*: $tc_failed

(I have no way to test this, and have very limited experience with Groovy; but hopefully this can at least put you on the right track.)